# Ubuntu funny suspend behavior

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

I have an Ubuntu installed on a Dell Vostro 1000 Laptop. Everything was excellent and I'm so happy.

However, there's one thing that render me sick, it's the suspend/resume.

When I'm in a graphic interface (the default of Ubuntu 9.10, not so sure what kind of GUI is it), if I suspend, then resume, then my Ubuntu hang, screen go dark, neither of caps lock nor numlock works.

When I'm in console interface (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), then execute pm-suspend, then my Ubuntu will resume properly.

And this is the most funny stuff: Right after resume in console interface, if I try to switch to graphic interface (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) then my Ubuntu will be hang. However, If I wait for few seconds, after Ubuntu log this error to the console screen:

```
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.432550] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.432559] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.432566] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.432569] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.432580] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.432586] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.437776] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.437780] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.437784] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.437786] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.437792] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.437795] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.449258] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.449267] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.449274] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.449276] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.449288] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.449294] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.466219] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.466228] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.466235] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.466237] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.466248] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.466254] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.470781] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.470786] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.470792] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.470794] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.470801] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.470805] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.475415] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.475422] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.475428] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.475430] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.475440] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.475446] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.480159] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.480163] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.480167] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.480169] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.480175] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:42 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.480178] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.568142] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.568148] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.568155] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.568157] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.568167] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.568172] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 176844
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.572717] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.572720] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.572726] Info fld=0x56598, ILI
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.572727] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Jan 15 09:56:43 phuongnd08-laptop kernel: [   27.572733] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1414752
```

(I copyied this log from `/var/log/syslog` file, not exactly like what displayed in the console)

Then I can switch to graphic interface by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and continue my work.

Is there any reason for such funny stuff?

Any solution should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1371844) from the Ubuntu Forums.

---

1. Go to launchpad an download the most recent Jaunty driver for your ATI video card. Here is the link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archiv...-archive-extra

   Download the following:

   - For 64bit systems:

     - `xserver-xorg-video-ati_6.12.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`
     - `xserver-xorg-video-radeon_6.12.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`
   - For 32bit systems:

     - `xserver-xorg-video-ati_6.12.1-0ubuntu2_i386.deb`
     - `xserver-xorg-video-radeon_6.12.1-0ubuntu2_i386.deb`
2. Now in your shell, type:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-downgrade <xxx>/xserver-xorg-video-radeon_6.12.1-0ubuntu2_<yyy>.deb

   sudo dpkg -i --force-downgrade <xxx>/xserver-xorg-video-ati_6.12.1-0ubuntu2_<yyy>.deb
   ```

   Note: Replace `<xxx>` with the path to the folder where you stored the packages and replace `<yyy>` with `amd64` or`i386`, depending on your architecture.
3. Reboot the system and try to suspend and resume to see if the fix worked.

   - **3a**. If it worked, you need to keep Synaptic from updating the drivers to the (broken) Karmic drivers. Do so by typing in your shell:

     ```
     aptitude hold xserver-xorg-video-radeon
     aptitude hold xserver-xorg-video-ati
     ```
   - **3b**. If it did not work: Skip **3a** and startup the Update manager to replace the drivers with the current ones. This should restore your system to the point before following this little guide.

Comment: This works like a charm. I google for weeks but cannot figure it out, thanks a lot.